# Separate fill for each shape in Flex graphics

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, graphics, drawing, flex3

I am drawing a bunch of circles in 2 horizontal rows across a sprite and would like a gradient applied to each circle individually but flex is applying it to the entire graphics area. What do I need to change to draw each circle with its own gradient?

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
var g:Graphics = s.graphics;
g.beginBitmapFill(bd, new Matrix(), false, false);
g.drawRect(0, 0, s.width, s.height);
g.endFill();
var m:Matrix = new Matrix();
g.lineStyle(1, 0x888888, 1);
for(var i:int = 0; i < numSpirals; i++) {
    g.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, [0x666666, 0xFFFFFF], [1, 1], [0, 255], m);
    xc = i * spiralWidth + spiralHoleRadius;
    yc = bdCenter - (spiralBoxHeight / 2) + (spiralHoleRadius / 2);
    g.drawCircle(xc, yc, spiralHoleRadius);
    g.endFill();
}
for(i = 0; i < numSpirals; i++) {
    g.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, [0x666666, 0xFFFFFF], [1, 1], [0, 255], m);
    xc = i * spiralWidth + spiralHoleRadius;
    yc = bdCenter + (spiralBoxHeight / 2) - (spiralHoleRadius / 2);
    g.drawCircle(xc, yc, spiralHoleRadius);
    g.endFill();
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit - I forgot this part (may or may not be relevant). Before drawing the circles I drew the BitmapData from an ImageSnapshot of some UI elements onto the sprite as well.

**Solution:**

I needed to create a new matrix and 'createGradientBox' for each circle individually

```
    m = new Matrix();
    m.createGradientBox(spiralHoleRadius * 2, spiralHoleRadius * 2, 0, xc - spiralHoleRadius / 2, yc - spiralHoleRadius / 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is a simular question on this site, maybe it helps (I cannot comment so I put this in a answer)
[AS3: beginGradientFIll() doesn't make me a gradient!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561225/as3-begingradientfill-doesnt-make-me-a-gradient)

Comment: I was able to infer the solution from that question/answer after some more trial and error. Turns out I needed to create a new matrix and apply the 'createGradientBox' to the matrix for each circle individually.